# Can't access internet in Chrome, Internet Browser

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, browser, internet

The problem is little weird, I'm unable to access internet via Chrome and Samsung's default internet browser.

The error that appears is : **Connection Refused**. 
Whereas I can easily access from other Apps like Opera and UC Browser. Everything else is working fine.

For example -  When I open facebook in app it works fine whereas when I try to open in Chrome/Browser. I get this error. This happens both on WiFi and mobile data.

Please help.

Device Information -  Samsung Galaxy S4 - I9500, Ozcan ROM, 4.4.2.

Comment: Have, you tried clearing the cache and the data stored by the Chrome and the Facebook application by heading over to the settings>application manager and see if that works out for you !

Comment: Tried that, still getting the same issue :(

Comment: Are you using any adblocker service over your device??

Comment: @PeterCarlos - Oh yes!! I installed it yesterday. But that time the net was working fine. What should I do now?

Comment: @PeterCarlos - But.. I don't want to uninstall it as I'm getting lots of ads on my browser. I can't even browse either way. Is there any other way/alternative. So can use them both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18582/discussion-between-peter-carlos-and-pankaj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the adblocker, try uninstalling the adblocker services and try restarting the device, and open Google Chrome to see if that works out for you !

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is facing the same issue: I had the same problem, I couldn't use Chrome with mobile network and turning off the adblocker didn't help. What I did to resolve the issue was to set up a new APN. Try every possible APN for your provider.